# How to express that dx is a single variable?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was wondering how you would express that $dx$ as a whole variable and not two multiplied variables $(d)(x)$ in order to define the derivative. This is what I mean:

Let $S(x)\equiv{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}$

How do I say that $\{S(C)\equiv{\frac{d}{dx}f(C)},\neg{\frac{d}{dC}f(C):C=\mbox{some constant}}\}$, meaning that you are not substituting into the $x=C$ in $dx$?

**Which logic symbols would you use to indicate that $dx$ is a single variable?**

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Ian Which part?

Comment: The whole thing; you're really confused about how notation for derivatives works. The one difficulty that is an actual difficulty in practice is with the distinction between $\frac{d}{dx}$ of an expression (where the expression needs to depend on $x$ for this to make any sense) and $\frac{df}{dx}$ of an expression (where technically if $f$ was defined in terms of the symbol $x$ then the expression plugged into it needn't depend on $x$ again). Sometimes in the case of the latter scenario we will write things like $\left. \frac{df}{dx} \right |_{x=a}$ to disambiguate things.

Comment: $dx$ is not a variable.

Comment: @Ian From what I understand, dx is defined as single variable in the derivative, and am trying to understand what kind logic symbols would indicate that dx is one variable.

Comment: There isn't any fancy syntax, we just understand what is meant. The use of the slightly different symbol $\mathrm{d} x$ can help a little bit but $dx$ is understood also. (In any case in standard analysis differentials are just elements of syntax, not variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments have pointed out, what you are writing down doesn't make much sense. Admittedly, there are numerous ways to understand the derivative (e.g. as rate of change, as an operator/linear map, etc.). Symbolically, writing the "$dx$" in the 'denominator' of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is not to interpret $dx$ as a variable. This is just how the derivative is written. What you might be getting confused about is the fact that the $dx$ in the bottom of $\frac{d}{dx}$ denotes the derivative of a function with respect to the *single variable* $x$.

In general, we could have a function $f(x,y)$ which depends on two variables $x$ and $y$, but we might only be interested in its derivative with respect to $x$. In which case, $\frac{d}{dx}f$ (in this case, we usually use the slightly different notation $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f$ for partial derivative) denotes the derivative with respect to the single variable $x$ (despite $f$ depending on two variables $x$ and $y$).

In summary, $dx$ is **not** a single variable (whereas $x$ is a single variable). In fact, what $dx$ really is depends a lot at the level of mathematical sophistication you are at (we usually think of $dx$ as something called a $1$-form, $d$ being something called the *exterior derivative*). But for our intents and purposes, we should just think of $dx$ appearing in the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ as denoting taking a derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Can you tell me more about external derivatives or drop a link to a good explanation? And does that mean you can, in certain cases, cancel out the d or dx, like in the chain rule or something?

Comment: To really understand the exterior derivative, you'll need to understand the context it comes up in, which would be (differentiable/smooth) manifolds. Probably the most standard textbook to learn this subject from is Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, by John M. Lee. The exterior derivative is introduced in Chapter 14 there. Clearly, that's a lot of pre-req. material to get through. You can check out this wikipedia article for a brief introduction: [Wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)